# Calculating the age by radioactive dating

Tags: radioactivity, geochemistry

The following was an example done in class, so I know the answer and (maybe?) the formula, but I still can't derive it for myself, and I would appreciate some help.

> Given a sample of biotite with $\ce{K2O} = 9~\%,~~ \ce{^{40}Ar} = 2.242~\mathrm{\mu g/g}$, find the age.

The constants given were $x_e= 0.581 \cdot 10^{-10}\ \mathrm{y^{-1}}$, $x=5.543 \cdot 10^{-10}\ \mathrm{y^{-1}}$ where $x$ is the decay constant, isotopic abundance of $\ce{^{40}K} = 0.01167~\%$, and relative atomic masses $M_\mathrm{r}(\ce{K}) = 39.098, M_\mathrm{r}(\ce{O}) = 15.999, M_\mathrm{r} (\ce{^{40}Ar}) =39.96$.

The answer shown was $2308 \cdot 10^6~\mathrm{y}$.

The formula I'm used to for this type of problem is $t=\frac{1}{x} \ln(\frac{\ce{^{40}Ar}^*}{\ce{^{40}K}} (x/x_e +1))$ but I'm not sure how to apply that given just a percentage of $\ce{K}$ instead of a mass.  I thought of just finding the weight percentage of $\ce{K}$ from the $9~\%$ (its $80.46~\%$ of the $\ce{K_2O}$, or $7.2~\%$ of the total), but that didn't work.  I'm not sure if I need to consider atmospheric $\ce{Ar}$ either.

I tried $^{40}K = .09 * .83022 * .0001167 = 8.719 *10^{-6}$ where .833022 is the weight percentage and it didn't give the correct answer.

I also tried $^{40}K = .09 * .6666667 * .0001167 = 7.002 *10^{-6}$ using the molar percentage of K, but also didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: ?!? "Given a sample of biotite with $K_2O$=9%, $^{40}Ar$=2.242 ug/g, find the age." // $K_2O$=9% that means 0.09 g  $\ce{K2O}$  per gram of  sample // $^{40}Ar$=2.242 ug/g means 2.242 ug $^{40}Ar$ per gram of sample.

Comment: I hope I didn’t mess up your formula while improving the MathJax ^^'

Comment: @Jan, thanks for fixing that!  I'm new to using MathJax and I always for get how to do fractions.